# How to insert current date into table using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am having a table with name medium and there is a column name medium name and creation date i have created stored procedure to insert specific above two values .below is my stored procedure

```
alter procedure insertmediumproc
    @MediumName varchar(50) ,@CreationDate datetime
as 
begin
    insert into medium  (MediumName, CreationDate) values(@MediumName,getdate())
end
```

when i tried to insert values in table with command below:

```
exec insertmediumproc Nepali,getdate()
```

it is showing error below:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want the current date as the value for the CreationDate column you could use a default on the table and modify your proc to just take @mediumnamn as parameter. Or you could modify it to this:

```
alter procedure insertmediumproc @MediumName varchar(50)
as begin
insert into medium (MediumName, CreationDate) values (@MediumName,getdate())
end
```

That way you don't have to send the date as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes around `Nepali`

```
exec insertmediumproc 'Nepali', getdate()
```

And your insert statement should be

```
insert into medium (MediumName, CreationDate) 
values (@MediumName, @CreationDate)
```

And if you only need a `date` then you can change the parameter type from `datetime` to `date`

Comment: still i am getting same error,My table contains Meium Id,MediumName, CreationDate,Status(default constraint already gvn to 1)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error - you are not passing in a proper `VARCHAR` - you need to quote the value:

```
exec insertmediumproc 'Nepali',getdate()
```